# How to restrict the first fetch call to happen only when the view is visible in the viewport

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer, react-intersection-observer

I am using `useInfiniteQuery` hook for infinite scrolling items in my component. I want that the first fetch happens only when the view is visible in the viewport . I am using `useInView`/intersection observer for finding if the view is visible in viewport.

I am using `useInView`/intersection observer for finding if the view is visible in viewport, but unable to restrict the first fetch on the basis of this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about the `useInfiniteQuery` hook from `@tanstack/react-query`. This hook actually inherits all options from `useQuery`, which takes an `enabled` property, that determines when it will be triggered.
Assuming you have a boolean that determines the state of your `IntersectionObserver`, you could do something like this:

```js
useInfiniteQuery('data', fetchData, {
    enabled: valueFromIntersectionObserver
});
```

Refer to the [documentation of the `useQuery` hook](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery) for more details.